# Find minimum across multiple worksheet using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, min, worksheet

How can I find the minimum values among multiple worksheets for each index across total worksheet

suppose,

```
  worksheet 1

    index    A   B   C
       0     2   3   4.28
       1     3   4   5.23
    worksheet 2

    index    A   B   C
        0    9   6   5.9
        1    1   3   4.1

    worksheet 3

    index    A   B   C
        0    9   6   6.0
        1    1   3   4.3
 ...................(Worksheet 4,Worksheet 5)...........
by comparing C column, I want an answer, where dataframe looks like

index      min(c)
    0       4.28
    1       4.1
```

Comment: Only one answer can be accepted ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(np.fmin, [ws1.C, ws2.C, ws3.C])

index
0    4.28
1    4.10
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

---

This generalizes nicely with a comprehension

```
reduce(np.fmin, [w.C for w in [ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4, ws5]])
```

---

If you must insist on your column name

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(np.fmin, [ws1.C, ws2.C, ws3.C]).to_frame('min(C)')

       min(C)
index        
0        4.28
1        4.10
```

---

You can also use `pd.concat` on a dictionary and use `pd.Series.min` with the `level=1` parameter

```
pd.concat(dict(enumerate([w.C for w in [ws1, ws2, ws3]]))).min(level=1)
# equivalently
# pd.concat(dict(enumerate([w.C for w in [ws1, ws2, ws3]])), axis=1).min(1)

index
0    4.28
1    4.10
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

**Note:**

```
dict(enumerate([w.C for w in [ws1, ws2, ws3]]))
```

is another way of saying

```
{0: ws1.C, 1: ws2.C, 2: ws3.C}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with parameter `sheetname=None` for `OrderedDict`s from [all sheetnames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-sheets) and then list comprehension with `reduce` with [`numpy.fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.fmin.html):

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname=None)
print (dfs)
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',    A  B     C
0  2  3  4.28
1  3  4  5.23), ('Sheet2',    A  B    C
0  9  6  5.9
1  1  3  4.1), ('Sheet3',    A  B    C
0  9  6  6.0
1  1  3  4.3)])

from functools import reduce

df = reduce(np.fmin, [v['C'] for k,v in dfs.items()])
print (df)
0    4.28
1    4.10
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([v['C'] for k,v in dfs.items()],axis=1).min(axis=1)
print (df)
0    4.28
1    4.10
dtype: float64
```

---

If need define index in `read_excel`:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname=None, index_col='index')
print (dfs)
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',        A  B     C
index            
0      2  3  4.28
1      3  4  5.23), ('Sheet2',        A  B    C
index           
0      9  6  5.9
1      1  3  4.1), ('Sheet3',        A  B    C
index           
0      9  6  6.0
1      1  3  4.3)])


df = pd.concat([v['C'] for k,v in dfs.items()], axis=1).min(axis=1)
print (df)
index
0    4.28
1    4.10
dtype: float64
```